# is there a method to extract adj nous pairs for french (with conjunction)

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

i want to extract all NOUN - ADJ pairs (with conjunction and coreference) from a texts using spacy ? is there any method or solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want adjacent words you can simply use a Matcher. I don't speak French, so using English as an example:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

pattern = [{"POS": "ADJ"}, {"POS": "NOUN"}]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("adj-noun", [pattern])

doc = nlp("I saw a red door and a big egg.")
for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc):
    print(doc[start:end])
# => red door
# => big egg
```

You can read more about how this works at the [rule based matching docs](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching).